# SQL find distinct values count, 2 times repeated values count, 3 times repeated values count and so on

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

For Example,

```
AAA
BBB
BBB
CCC
BBB
CCC
DDD
DDD
```

There are 4 unique values `(AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD)`, 2 two times repeated values
`(CCC, DDD)`, 1 three times repeated values `(BBB)`. I want to write a sql query for this problem. please help

So the answer is 4, 2, 1.

Comment: This looks like homework. Have you done anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I am using Amazon Redshift

Comment: The only value that is unique is AAA. The answer is actually 3,2,1

Comment: Sorry I changed the question - distinct not unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select, seqnum, count(*)
from (select col, row_number() over (partition by col) as seqnum
      from t
      group by col
     ) h
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```